# php - Test has the SESSION user viewed page X?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a simple notification system, which, like notification systems should, notifies the user if a new comment has been posted to a page of the user's.

In order to build this, I'm planning on giving each page incorporated into the notification system an additional `hasViewed` variable in the the page database, and then simply spit out the values where `hasViewed = 0`.

Only problem is, how to test if the `SESSION` user has viewed a page?  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. The script that displays the pages sets `hasViewed` to 1 for the page and user.

Comment: i don't know how the script sets hasViewed to 1.

Comment: You said you were going to put it in a database. So the script that displays pages performs a database update, and the script that tests whether they've viewed the page performs a database query.